# Security Integration between Windows Authentication Intranet and ASP.NET Identity MVC Website

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, asp.net-identity, intranet

I am looking for a solution whereby a pre-authenticated (windows authentication) intranet user can gain access to an MVC Website (ASP.NET Identity) without manually logging in.

The MVC site currently has individual logins for manual login access to none authenticated users which is intended behaviour but what I want to achieve is SSO when accessing the MVC site from the Intranet. Either by passing an authentication cookie or bearer access token which i can decipher in my MVC website.

I currently have a plain old hyperlink from the intranet with a URL to the MVC application which is protected by a custom authorize attribute...I have overriden the AuthorizeAttribute but need the authentication to persist for the duration of the session.

Please can someone provide some guidance on this with example code to generate the web request and the necessary headers and authenticate the windows user within the the MVC AuthorizeCore method?

Many thanks,

Steveo

Comment: Can you not just use IIS-level Windows Authentication? By the time MVC sees the request, it will have already been authenticated (or not).

Comment: Unfortunately not. The intranet application resides on an internal server with access to LDAP but the website resides on a webfarm with no access to the internal servers (except via autheticated web API requests). The ASP.NET Identity is implemented on the MVC site so the user needs to be authenticated before any data can be returned from Web API. Ideally, I could do with granting access to an administrator login when the request comes from the intranet but I need to keep this 100% secure so would like to make use of access tokens or an authentication cookie. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to solve your problem.

1. Open up Visual Studio 2013, hit FILE->New->Project.
2. Under Project, hit Web->VisualStudio2012-> ASP.NET MVC4 Web Application.

[image]

3. Type your project name, check Create Folder, selected Intranet Application and hit Ok.

[image]

[image]

4. Modify the root web.config, add the allow users tag under the authorization tag:

```html
   <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

5. Test run using Google Chrome and this home page should show up:

[image]